# 食べていました and its use

Tags: grammar, て-form, subsidiary-verbs

I was wondering about **__ていました** and its use. By this I mean, is it possible to turn a て form verb into ていました? For example, would you ever use 食べていました instead of 食べました?

Just wondering if it is possible or necessary to use the past tense of ています instead of the typical ました.

Answer (score 2):

You usually learn about いる with other subsidiary verbs such as みる、おく、いく、くる、しまう、…

They all follow the *te*-form of a verb, are usually written in *kana* and slightly change the meaning of the verb.

～ている is often translated with the progressive in English

> りんごを食べている
> I am eating an apple

You can think of combination of [*te*-form of a verb] + [subsidiary verb] as a new verb. Conjugation is done on the subsidiary verb. For example

> past tense of *masu*-form of 　　　　いる = 　　　いました
> past tense of *masu*-form of 　食べて**いる** = 食べて**いました**　"I was eating"
>
> past tense of *masu*-form of 　　　食べる = 食べ　　ました　"I ate"

Literally いる means "to be/exist/stay", so literally, 食べて居る【いる】 means "to eat and stay [that way]".

The fact that this literal meaning is lost makes いる a subsidiary verb. That the literal meaning is lost is also a good reason to write いる without *kanji*.

(This is the same with other subsidiary verbs. For example, ～てみる is often translated "to try to [verb]". Literally, 食べて見る means "to eat and see [what happens]". This literal meaning is lost and みる as subsidiary verb is written in *kana*.)

---

*N.B.* in ～ている the い is often omitted in colloquial speech/writing, e.g.

> 食べてた = 食べて**い**た "I was eating"